# Empty HTTP body in jQuery AJAX request in IE8, works in Chrome/FF/Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

This AJAX request works in Chrome/FF/Safari:

```
  $.ajax({
     url: 'foo.php?random=' + Math.random(),
     data: $('form#foo').serialize(),
     type: 'get',
     success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp); // prints some HTML
     }
  });
```

I usually use `random=' + Math.random()` so IE doesn't cache AJAX responses.

Some HTML is meant to be returned from the server and HTTP response code is 200.  However, with IE8, I get 200 code but an empty HTTP body.

Things I have tried:

- `dataType: 'text' # same problem`
- `dataType: 'html' # same problem`
- `dataType: 'jsonp' # same problem, breaks Chrome, request is local anyway`

There are no server errors.

I have no idea what IE8 is trying to do :(.  Any help would be great, thanks.

If I return the text `"test"` from the server then I get a response.

[jQuery GET not reading HTML response data in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955638/jquery-get-not-reading-html-response-data-in-ie) does not solve this issue.  My HTML is a single table row with about 5 cells.

Comment: Did you give a look into developer tools to try to catch any possible error?

Comment: Yes.  No errors but Content-Length is 0.

Comment: Did you tried setting X-UA-Compatible in your server page? .php/.jsp/.asp

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge

Comment: Were you able to solve it? It looks similar to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402228/web-service-error-in-jquery-while-using-internet-explorer-10/18403799#18403799